# One to one relationship with foreign key to mutiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Please let me start by saying, I know this has been asked many times before and I've studied other questions (and answers) but after 2 days of reading questions and amending my database I can't get this to work as I want.

At the moment I have various tables, for example `customer`, `supplier`, `product`, `banner`, etc.

I have a table called `custom_field` which allows custom fields to be created and used against various other tables.

At the moment some of my tables look like this:

```
General Tables
==============

Customer
+-------------+---------------+
| customer_id | customer_name |
+-------------+---------------+
| 1           | Peter         |
| 2           | Sally         |
+-------------+---------------+

Banner
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| banner_id | banner_name | banner_width |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1         | Easter      | 100px        |
| 2         | Xmas        | 250px        |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+

Tables for managing custom fields
=================================

Custom_Field
+----------+------------+----------------+-----------+
| field_id | field_name | field_label    | item_type |
+----------+------------+----------------+-----------+
| 100      | fav_color  | Favorite Color | customer  |
| 101      | border     | Border         | banner    |
+----------+------------+----------------+-----------+

Custom_Field_Value
+----------+----------+---------+-------------+
| value_id | field_id | item_id | field_value |
+----------+----------+---------+-------------+
| 1567     | 100      | 1       | Red         |
| 1568     | 100      | 2       | Blue        |
| 1569     | 101      | 1       | Solid       |
| 1570     | 101      | 2       | Dotted      |
+----------+----------+---------+-------------+
```

To clarify, `item_id` refers to a `customer_id`, a `banner_id`, or a `supplier_id`, etc.  In the example above this means Peter has a "favorite color" custom field set to Red, and Sally has a "favorite color" custom field set to Blue.

The Easter Banner has a "border" custom field set to solid, and the Xmas Banner has a "border" custom field set to Dotted.

This all works fine, except there can be no foreign key or referential integrity set between `Custom_field_value.item_id` and `Customer.customer_id` (or `Banner.banner_id`) because item_id's context is described by the `item_type` field in the `Custom_Field` table.

I don't want to create multiple nullable foreign keys (not sure that would even work anyway) as it will become unmanageable.

I did try creating sub tables, for example `customer_custom_field`, and relate this between `Customer` and `Custom_Field`, but again it becomes unmanageable when you consider every table could potentially have custom fields.

A single field value would only ever apply to a single entity from another table.

As an aside I also want to create an `Attachments` table for managing uploaded attachments to a particular entity, and again that could apply to customers, suppliers, products and various other tables, so it's a similar issue.

Comment: in your research, did you come across "Class Table Inheritance"?  If you tried that without success, can you add a bit on that to your question?

Comment: ... aka SQL/database subtyping/polymorphism.

Comment: Also read re pros & cons of EAV. Its constraints need triggers. EAV tables are metadata tables for the tables you really want, ie your application hand-encodes a DBMS. Is using DDL to modify tables like normal so impractical for your application? PS What is your question?